# shuffling a two-dimensional array in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a data file like a two-dimensional array

```
22950   12
80044   22
02942   06
42018   20
63829   10
...
```

I want to shuffle this array into a random order, like

```
42018   20
22950   12
...
```

Looks like the 'shuffle' in List can be used to shuffle a vector, how to keep handle this kind of two-dimensional array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are only shuffling the first dimension of the array, `List::Util::shuffle` will work without any modification.

Perl does not have multi-dimentional arrays, it has arrays of scalars, each of which can also be an array.  This is effectively a multi-dimentional array, but it means that you can use normal array operations like `shuffle`, since `shuffle` does not care what the values of the array are (and in this case they will be other arrays).

so the line:

```
my @random = shuffle \@array1, \@array2, \@array3;
```

is the same as

```
my @random = shuffle 1, 2, 3;
```

as far as `shuffle` is concerned (a list of 3 elements to shuffle).

so assuming your 2D data is contained in the array `@data`

```
my @data = (
    [1234, 34],
    [4564, 45],
    ...
);
```

then you would just write:

```
use List::Util 'shuffle';
my @random = shuffle @data;
```

and then you would access the 2D structure normally:

```
say $random[0][1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Eric is correct that you can shuffle multidimensional arrays as though they were scalars. However, if you have a file such as in your example, you can simply do:

```
perl -MList::Util=shuffle -lwe 'print shuffle <>' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: thanks, TLP. By the way, what does -lwe stand for in your answer?

Comment: @user288609 : `-lwe` is a shorter way of writing `-l -w -e`. These are flags that activate certain behaviors within Perl that are documented in [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

Comment: @user288609 `-l` is used to process line endings, more specifically make sure there's newlines in the right places. `-w` is warnings, `-e` means to run the following text as a one-line program.

Answer (score 0):

I will use someting without module, like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @liste = (['22950','12'],
['80044','22'],['02942','06'],['42018','20'],['63829','10']);

print $_->[0], ' ',$_->[1], "\n" foreach ( @liste);

foreach (1 .. 10) {
  fisher_yates_shuffle( \@liste );
  print "=======\n";
  print $_->[0], ' ',$_->[1], "\n" foreach ( @liste);
}

sub fisher_yates_shuffle {
    my $deck = shift;  # $deck is a reference to an array
    my $i = @$deck;
    while (--$i) {
        my $j = int rand ($i+1);
        @$deck[$i,$j] = @$deck[$j,$i];
    }
}
```